# How can i take method result from other class?

Tags: java

I have 2 constructor classes, Course and Student. Student class have test scores and method that computes average of those tests. Course class have array list of Students, and my goal is to take average scores of all Students in array and compute average score, but i dont understand how to take avg value(result from average method from Student class) and use it in average method in Course class.

I tried to make another method getAverage in Student class, and then call it in average method in Course class, for each student. But thats not allowed, and not sure if that would work.

```
public Student(String first, String last, Address home, Address school) {

    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    homeAddress = home;
    schoolAddress = school;
}
public double average() {
    avg = (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3.0;
    return avg;
}
// Thats part of Student class

public Course(String name) {
    courseName = name;
    students = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
public boolean addStudent(Student person) {
    if (!students.contains(person)) {
        students.add(person);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public double average() { // Having trouble with creating this method

}
```

I can provide additional info if needed. Thanks in advance !
EDIT: Adding what i tried.

```
public double getAverage() {
    return avg;
 }
// GetAverage method in Student class

public double average() { // average method i tried in Course class
    double average, studentAvg, sum;
    studentAvg.getAverage(); // It isses error at this line
    sum += studentAvg;
    average = sum / students.size();
    return average;

 }
```

Comment: *thats not allowed*: why wouldn't it be allowed? Post the code you tried, tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead, precisely. Include the exact and complete error you get, if any.

Comment: How would a `getAverage()` method in the Student class differ from the `average()` method that already exists?

Comment: 1.) "I have 2 constructor classes" - there is no thing such as a *constructor class*. What do you mean by that? 2.) "Student class have test scores" - even if there are always exactly 3, naming them `test1`, `test2` and `test3` is a bad idea. Use a list. 3.) "my goal is to take average grades" - what is a grade now? Until here here was no grade, but only scores. Do you use grade and score interchangeably? Stick to one term.

Comment: I added code that i tried in original post. @JB Nizet
1.) Im creating object from Student class in Course class, and from Course class in driver class.
2. I edited grades to scores, so there is no confusion. Im sorry for making rooky mistakes, still learning java.
And i tought that getAverage() method would return avg value without calculating it again, unlike average method.

Comment: *It isses error at this line*: you need to **read** the error. It means something. To call a method in Java, you need parentheses: `studentAvg.getAverage()`. But to call a method on a local variable like `studentAvg`, the variable must be initialized. You really need to step back and 1. read the basic syntax of Java; 2. Think about what an average is, and how it is computed. An average is a sum divided by a size. So you need to sum the averages of every student. So you need to loop over the students.

Comment: You talk about errors and something not working, but we need to **see** the error you're getting and you need to explain exactly what isn't working. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Okey, i got it. Arrays cannot be read without loops. I make some syntax mistakes from time to time, still new to this. Thanks for help !

Answer (score -2):

In order to get total average of Students,
Need to iterate all the students and calculate overall average.

```
Summation of All student average / number of students.


public double average() {
    if (students.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    double sum = 0;
    for (Student s: students) {
        sum += s.average();
    }
    return sum/students.size();
}
```

Comment: Just this, without any explanation why it works and what it does?

Comment: It was very helpful, actually. Thank you!